# Displaying a "close" icon upon hover

Tags: html, css, background, hover

I have a newsfeed which is obviously organized by an . When the user hovers over each of the items, the background is highlighted. I'd also like to have a small "x" in the top right hand corner of each item, only shown when hovered. This "x" would be a delete button to remove that post.

Right now I just have some basic html stating: `<div class="hide-button"><a href="#">x</a></div>`

I know that I don't want the "x" displayed in the html, but rather have it in the CSS. So I have the `<li>` css below for hovering, as well as the CSS for the hide button. I'd like to know the best method to integrate the hide button div into the `<li>`

```
.hide-button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -13px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    color: gray;
}

.hide-button a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:gray;
}

.hide-button a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:gray;
}
```

and the list:

```
.newsfeedlist li {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
    padding: 12px 0px 12px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.newsfeedlist li:hover {
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
}
```

Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Could you add your HTML? A [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far would also be helpful.

Comment: of course, give me a sec

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presuming your delete buttons are inside another container you could do something like

```
.hide-button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -13px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    color: tray;
    display: none;
}

... the other bits of CSS ...

.newsfeedlist li:hover .hide-button {
    display: block;
}
```

Modifying the close button to be hidden by default and then when hovering on a list item you set the display back again on the close button.

Hope this makes sense

Tim

Comment: You are a superhuman Tim, thank you. Very simple solution, but works perfectly. Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Not a problem. Don't forget to mark an answer so others can see this question has been answered. Tim.

Answer (score 2):

But `hide-button` element in the `li` and do

```
.newsfeedlist li:hover .hide-button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and add `display: none;` to `.hide-button`

Otherwise, there's always javascript.

Comment: Thank you! Same as above, and a reason for that :D

Answer (score 2):

You might really be in need of this:
[Demo at jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/DrkwB/2/)
I modified an example and tushed it up for multiple content areas or images.

Comment: I added event for the close icon's click to hide the parent container: See demo at [http://jsfiddle.net/DrkwB/4/]